# Employer wants insight in backlog

Tags: scrum, backlog

I'm currently involved in a scrum project for a small organization.

Some events have led us to believe the organization doesn't understand their role in the scrum process. We've already gone as far as arguing about the size of the development team which, in my opinion, shouldn't be something for them to worry about (negative conclusion to this project has little to no impact on their end and large impact on us).

Learning the lingo as they go, they've asked us if they could see our backlog.

I don't have a ton of experience with scrum but is it wise to show it?

I fear we might get a lot of negative feedback because they don't understand the process all that well.

(Additional context: we are students and this situation is not covered by our classes, our teacher hasn't responded to our e-mails yet.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the scrum process, not about coding per se. It seems as though http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask such a question.

Comment: @Mureinik - this seems to be less about scrum and more about internal politics.  A question about scrum would be on-topic at Programmers, but questions about internal politics is definitely off-topic.

Comment: - edit: delete this comment, I'm being defensive and ruse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrum is transparent. Everything the team does is open and visibile to all interested parties. Regular showcases are held to demonstrate completed work and both the sprint and project backlogs are public.

If you are following the Scrum framework then you will have a Product Owner who represents the business and is fully engaged with the team. It is the Product Owners responsibility to engage with stakeholders (i.e. other business users) to explain the contents of the product backlog.

Comment: Thank you. This is most helpful.